One-bit ALU test bench
I am attempting to write a test bench in VHDL for a one-bit ALU.
Here is the design file:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity alu_1bit is
Port ( a : in std_logic; b : in std_logic; 
ci : in std_logic; less : in std_logic; 
binvert : in std_logic;
Op : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
co : out std_logic; 
result : out std_logic);
end alu_1bit; 

architecture Behavioral of alu_1bit is

signal b_int : std_logic; 

begin

with binvert select 
    b_int <= b when '0', 
    not (b) when '1',
    'X' when others; 
with Op select
    result <= a and b_int when "00",

    a  or b_int when "01", 
    a xor b_int xor ci when "10",
    less when "11",
    '0' when others;
    co <= (a and b_int and not(ci)) or (a and not(b_int) and ci)
    or (not(a) and b_int and ci) or (a and b_int and ci); 
end Behavioral;

here is the test bench:

library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
entity alu_1bit_test is
END alu_1bit_test;
architecture behavior of alu_1bit_test is
-- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)
component alu_1bit
port( a : in std_logic; b : in
std_logic; ci : in
std_logic; less : in
std_logic; binvert : in
std_logic;
Op : in std_logic_vector(1 
downto 0); co : out std_logic; 
result : out std_logic);
end component;
-- Signals Declaration
--Inputs 
signal a : std_logic := '0'; 
signal b : std_logic := '0'; 
signal ci : std_logic := '0'; 
signal less : std_logic := '0'; 
signal binvert : std_logic := '0';
signal Op : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := (others => 
'0');
--Outputs 
signal co : std_logic; 
signal result : std_logic;
begin
-- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT) 
uut: alu_1bit port map ( a => a, 
b => b, 
ci => ci, 
less => less, 
binvert => binvert,
Op => Op, 
co => co, 
result => result);
-- Stimulus process 
stim_proc: process 
begin

-- or simulation 

Op <= "01"; 
binvert <= '0';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 10 ns; 
a <= '0'; 
b <= '1';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 20 ns;


-- and simulation 
Op <= "00"; 
binvert <= '0';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 10 ns; 
a <= '1'; 
b <= '1';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 20 ns;


-- sum simulation 
Op <= "10"; 
binvert <= '0';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 10 ns; 
a <= '1'; 
b <= '1';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 20 ns;

-- sub simulation 
Op <= "10"; 
binvert <= '1';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 10 ns; 
a <= '1'; 
b <= '0';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 20 ns;


-- slt simulation 
Op <= "11"; 
binvert <= '1';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 10 ns; 
a <= '1'; 
b <= '0';
less <='1';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 20 ns;

wait;
end process;
end;

What I would like to know is whether this test bench demonstrates that the ALU is working correctly.  Would this be the proper way to test that the slt, sub, and sum functions are working correctly?

Since you are a new user: What should I do when someone answers my question? ... Vote and Accept

The testbench code is a good first step towards verifying that your design works in simulation.
When I run your simulation on EDA Playground, there is no printed output to the log file (or console).  Printing output is one of the ways to determine if your design works properly.
Since you are not doing that, I assume you are looking at waveforms of your design inputs and outputs, which the EDA Playground simulator allows you to do.
The first function that you simulate is the OR function, based on the comment in your testbench code.  The waves show that you stimulate all 4 combinations of the 2 inputs, and the result looks as expected.
This is a basic approach to verification.  However, the drawback is that it is a manual process and is prone to human error.  A better approach is to add code to the testbench that automatically checks the outputs based on the design inputs at any given time.  This obviously requires more work for you, but the benefit is that you have higher confidence that the design works as desired.
For the SUM function, you only set the inputs to one set of values.  This is insufficient to verify that function.  You should set the inputs to all 8 possible combinations of values for the 3 inputs (a, b, cin).  Refer to the Added comment below:
-- sum simulation 
Op <= "10"; 
binvert <= '0';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 10 ns; 
a <= '1'; 
b <= '1';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 20 ns;
a <= '0'; -- Added
wait for 20 ns;
b <= '0';
wait for 20 ns;
-- Repeat 4 a/b combos for cin = 1 below


So would doing this suffice?

-- sum simulation 
Op <= "10"; 
binvert <= '0';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 10 ns; 
a <= '0'; 
b <= '0';
ci <='0';
wait for 10 ns; 
a <= '1'; 
b <= '0';
ci <='0';
wait for 10 ns; 
a <= '0'; 
b <= '1';
ci <='0';
wait for 10 ns; 
a <= '0'; 
b <= '0';
ci <='1';
wait for 10 ns; 
a <= '1'; 
b <= '1';
ci <='0';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1'; 
b <= '0';
ci <='1';
wait for 10 ns; 
a <= '0'; 
b <= '1';
ci <='1';
wait for 10 ns; 
a <= '1'; 
b <= '1';
ci <='1';
wait for 10 ns;
a <= '1';
wait for 20 ns;



@stiv: If that is all 8 combos, then it is sufficient.  As you can see, posting code into comments is hard to read.  Just try it out in your own simulation.
